# Передача параметра из сервлета в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Всем привет. 
Вопрос такой. Есть простейшее веб-приложение, чья логика должна получать текущую дату, заменять название дня недели и выводить полученное значение на JSP. Краткий код:

```
/* .model */
public class UserDate implements Serializable {

private String day;

public UserDate() {}

public UserDate(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}
/*getters and setters*/
```

Есть сервис, который с этим бином работает:

```
/* .service */
public class ServiceUserDate {

private String[] tamrielDays =
        {"Morndas", "Tirdas", "Middas",
                "Turdas", "Fredas", "Loredas", "Sundas"};

private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

public String getLoreDay() {

    String loreDay = "";
    DayOfWeek day = date.getDayOfWeek();
    DayOfWeek[] dayOfWeeks = DayOfWeek.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < dayOfWeeks.length; i++) {
        if (day.equals(dayOfWeeks[i])) {
            loreDay = tamrielDays[i];
        }
    }
    return loreDay;
}
```

И есть сервлет, который результат работы сервиса по получению даты должен отдавать JSP:

```
/* .controller */

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

static ServiceUserDate serviceUserDate = new ServiceUserDate();

public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
    try {
        super.init(servletConfig);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    UserDate date = new UserDate();
    date.setDay(serviceUserDate.getLoreDay());

    request.setAttribute("date", date);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Я говорю "должен", потому что на самом деле он упорно возвращает null, что бы я ни делал. Не помогли ни изменение порядка загрузки load-on-startup, ни попытки использовать jstl вместо скриптлетов, ничего. 
JSP выглядит так:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="date" scope="request" class="model.UserDate">
   <jsp:setProperty name="date" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">

    <p>
        <%= date.getDate() %>
    </p>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Я понятия не имею, как заставить это вывести простейшую переменную. Причем затык именно при получении даты; если вместо date.getDate() на странице вызвать date.toString(), то он нормально отработает, т.е. объект успешно создается перед тем, как выдать null на запросе getDate(). Проблема именно в установке даты. Этот "проект" планировался как легкая разгрузка головы перед изучением ORM: поделать разметку, покрутить стили, легкий такой фронтэнд... В итоге на Хибернейте написано два CRUD'а (там тоже сервлеты и JSP, тоже нужно получать и передавать запросы, все работает!), написаны первые хеллоуворлды на Spring, а этот null так никуда и не делся и воз и ныне там. В чем я ошибаюсь, какую элементарщину я упустил? Укажите на ошибку, ребят, или хотя бы подскажите, в какую сторону копать. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: А где метод getDate() в классе UserDate ?

Comment: Метод есть, само собой. Я там в закомментированной строке указал, что геттеры и сеттеры есть, чтобы очевидные детали кода не приводить. Стандартный геттер, public String getDate() { return day }, сеттер тоже стандартный, ничего особенного.

Comment: Попробуй сначала избавиться от скриптлетов.

Comment: Убрал скриптлет, вместо него для примера использовал <c:out value="${date}">. Ничего не поменялось: у объекта date все так же вызывается toString(), в котором возвращается строка "объект был создан с датой" + getDate(). Строка вызывается, getDate() возвращает null.